# Rename all sub elements with incremental number

Tags: powershell, recursion, rename

I'm new in powershell, I have to execute the following statement **recursively**:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("new_filename{0}.smali" -f $nr++)}
```

In other words I have to rename all the `.smali` files in the subdirectories with any other name different from the current one (keeping the `.smali` extension).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename files to increment filenumber using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706070/rename-files-to-increment-filenumber-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get-ChildItem -Path FolderPath -Filter *.smali -Recurse | ForEach-Object{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($*.BaseName + StringToAdd + $*.Extension) -WhatIf}

Copy the above line as is... Replace the values for FolderPath and StringToAdd and give it a try. If everything looks fine then execute it by removing the -Whatif switch.

Comment: with these changes it run    Get-ChildItem  -Filter *.sm
ali -Recurse | ForEach-Object{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.BaseNa
me + 'a' + $_.Extension)} however I want to completely remove the old file name, so i prefer this: Get-ChildItem  -Filter *.sm
ali -Recurse | ForEach-Object{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName ( "new_fil
ename{0}.smali" -f $nr++) }

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: since I do not want to keep the old file name I used the block    "new_fil ename{0}.smali" -f $nr++ which allows you to create several files with the name "fiename" + an incremental number

Answer (score 0):

`dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem` which has a `-Recursive` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nr = 0;    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.smali" | Rename-Item -NewName "new_filename$($nr++).smali"
```

Things to note:

DIR is an alias for Get-ChildItem. Get-ChildItem is more Powershell-y

Your command only looked at the top level directory, so I added the -recurse

Your command would rename all files, not just the "*.smali", so I added the filter.

Comment: with this code I get the following error:     Rename-Item : The argument can not be associated with the 'Path' parameter because it is null..
In raw:1 char:56
+ Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.smali" | Rename-Item $_
-NewName (" ...
+                                                        ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Rename-Item], Pa
   rameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNu
   llNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: Updated the command to initialize your counter as a first statement, then changed the format string for the new name a bit.